# separate mysql logins for each user of secure spring petclinic

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have added security to the spring petclinic sample in order to learn spring security.  I notice that the petclinic app is configured to log all users into MySQL using the same username and password.  How can I change petclinic's configuration so that each user of the petclinic app is able to use their own unique username and password to login to MySQL?

Here is [a link to the data-access.properties file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/data-access.properties).  Note that the MySQL section is uncommented in my version, while the HSQL section is deleted in my version.  The `jdbc.username` and `jdbc.password` that are currently referred to in `data-access.properties` would need to be set dynamically for each user.

Here is [a link to the entire code for the petclinic app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic).

I added `SecurityConfig.java` to the app to set up Spring security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .failureUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/somelogout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("MODERATOR")
            .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
            .and()
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);    
}
}
```

I also created a `User` class corresponding with a table of users in MySQL and a `Role` class corresponding with a table for roles in MySQL, along with boilerplate `Service` and `DAO` stuff in spring to manage the retrieval of authentication and authorization for each user.

I want MySQL to be able to record information about the user's activity using triggers, so I need to somehow send the user's identity into the database, and I imagined that the cleanest way to do this might be to have each user log into MySQL uniquely rather than embed the user's identity into every single component of the MVC architecture for a simple logging system.  I am using JPA, if that matters.

How do I set this up?

Comment: You don't. You should NEVER grant individual users direct access to the database. You create ONE account in mysql for the code to use, and then do your application level security in your own code. Unless you've created a TON of views in your db and only grant these users access to those views, where the view does security filtering, you'll have NO way of preventing people from rummaging around whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to do it.

Another would be to have an application level credential to MySQL, known only to the application.  You would not record activity information using triggers; you'd do it by inserting records at appropriate points in the application from the middle tier.  You'd create a session ID for each new user and associate events with it.

One user could have several sessions, so if knowing the individual mattered you'd have to find a way to associate the user credentials with the session.

But it would simplify the database and keep all the eventing on the middle tier.  It might easier to control that way using Java.  If you could make event INSERTs into the database asynchronous your response will be better, too.

Comment: No, sorry.  Pet clinic?   That was a J2EE demo problem from the late 90s.  Is that still relevant here?

Comment: I can get the session ID from `request.getSession().getId()` but I am imagining that your suggestion would require me to write a lot of code in a complicated architecture.  Can you point to a good example I can study so that I do not create unnecessary complexity?